# Bing Maps Touch Responsiveness to Map Pins on Mobile

Tags: bing-maps, responsive

I've created a Bing Maps tool to view High Schools and Competitions in out state.  The implementation works perfectly on the desktop.  You can click on a map pin, and you see either the School information or the Competition information.

However, I noticed today that on my iPhone, the map pins do not respond, i.e. the Info Box does not open.  I tried it in Chrome in Responsive mode, and I get the same thing.

I'm using the standard map pins on one and a FontAwesome map pin on the other, but neither is responsive.  What am I missing?

https://www.mshsaa.org/Activities/ClassAndDistrictAssignments.aspx?alg=3&class=1

https://www.mshsaa.org/Activities/Scoreboard.aspx?alg=3&view=map

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.  I guess I didn't give enough details.

It turns out I had bound show and hide of the Infoboxes to mouseover and mouseout.  I added binding to the "click" event, and that seems to work fine.  I did also need to explicitly hide all previously opened boxes, but that was pretty easy to do:

`Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(thisPin, 'click', function () { 
    $(".Infobox").parent().hide(); /* This hides the other open Infoboxes */
    infobox.setOptions({ visible: true }) 
});`